PySpark Serialization Issue with Kafka Producer in foreachPartition
i'm working with PySpark and trying to send a partitioned DataFrame to Kafka using the confluent-kafka library's Producer. However, I'm encountering a serialization problem with the Kafka producer on the Spark executors
Here is my code :
broadcast_config = spark.sparkContext.broadcast((kafka_broker, kafka_topic))

def send_partition_to_kafka(partition):
    kafka_broker, kafka_topic = broadcast_config.value

    for row in partition:
        producer = Producer(bootstrap_servers=kafka_broker,
                            value_serializer=lambda v: json.dumps(v).encode('utf-8'))
        producer.send(kafka_topic, value=row.asDict())

    producer.flush()

grouped_df.foreachPartition(send_partition_to_kafka)


and i keep getting this error  :
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/c2b_py_etl/spark-3.4.3-bin-hadoop3/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 812, in main
    func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_command(pickleSer, infile)
  File "/opt/c2b_py_etl/spark-3.4.3-bin-hadoop3/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 87, in read_command
    command = serializer._read_with_length(file)
  File "/opt/c2b_py_etl/spark-3.4.3-bin-hadoop3/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 174, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/opt/c2b_py_etl/spark-3.4.3-bin-hadoop3/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 472, in loads
    return cloudpickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
AttributeError: type object 'Producer' has no attribute '__bool__'


Despite instantiating the producer within each partition, the error persists. How can I resolve this serialization issue?
Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I think you import the class Producer in global scope to spark tries to serialise it and send it to executors, i think you should use the import inside your broadcasted method like
It should expected the module to be add to spark session dependencies and accessible from executors
broadcast_config = spark.sparkContext.broadcast((kafka_broker, kafka_topic))

def send_partition_to_kafka(partition):
    from module import Producer

    kafka_broker, kafka_topic = broadcast_config.value

    producer = Producer(bootstrap_servers=kafka_broker,
                            value_serializer=lambda v: json.dumps(v).encode('utf-8'))

    for row in partition:
        producer.send(kafka_topic, value=row.asDict())

    producer.flush()

grouped_df.foreachPartition(send_partition_to_kafka)

